# Tablor package with metapost files generation

Tags: pdftex, compiling, metapost

I want to use the [tablor package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tablor) but I get an issue with the compilation of the metapost file.

Here's my *tableau_variation.tex* file :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[xcas]{tablor}

\begin{document}
\initablor
\begin{TV}
  TV([-10,+infinity],[-1,1],"g","t",x^2/(x^2-1),1,n,\tv)
\end{TV}
\nettoyer
\end{document}
```

The compilation with  `pdflatex --shell-escape tableau_variation.tex` fails with :

```
! An expression can't begin with `right delimiter'.
<inserted text> 
            0
<to be read again> 
               )
l.20 beginTableau()
                newLigneVariables(btex $t$ etex);val(bte $-10$ etex);
?
```

So I inspected the mp file created by this process : `tableau_variation_Tab.mp`

I replaced `beginTableau()` with `beginTableau(0)` and compiled it with mpost.
The process succeded. So The .0 file was properly created.

In the `tablor.sty` file I can see lines with `beginTableau(+nmr+)`. I guess this is the way the mp file is created so the number `nmr` is not written correctly to the mp file.
Any idea ?

Comment: Did you read the warning on page 1 of the docs?  Apparently you need an update that is not on CTAN.

Comment: Attention !
À partir de la version 4.03 de tablor, il est nécessaire d’avoir la nouvelle version
de tableauVariation.mp (la 2.1 datant de décembre 2008) mais pour l’instant
elle n’est pas présente sur CTAN ! Récupérez plutôt le fichier à l’adresse
http://download.tuxfamily.org/tehessinmath/les_sources/tableauVariation.mp.

Comment: Roughly: Warning! above version 4.03 of tablor, you need the new version of `tableauVariation.mp` (version 2.1 dated
December 2008) but at present this file is not on CTAN.  You can download the file from:
http://download.tuxfamily.org/tehessinmath/les_sources/tableauVariation.mp.

Comment: I should have mentioned it: I've already downloaded the updated file. Its md5sum : 4294d88718cc758e33f5b944cf663ae5     So the truth is out there...